# Как открыть несколько файлов на сервере одной кнопкой?

Tags: javascript, html, link

На сайте имеется кнопка. Нужно что бы по клику на эту кнопку открывались в новых вкладках несколько файлов(предположим pdf документы). Можно ли это реализовать на JS(если можно, то хотелось бы узнать как) или может всё ещё проще?

Answer (score 0):

Мб как то так попробовать?

```
window.open('http://example.com');
```

https://learn.javascript.ru/popup-windows